# Cant perform Map Reduce Jobs. Invalid token exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have deployed HDP 2.6 with ambari on a 4 node cluster. ​The deployment went well, but now im not able to perform map reduce jobs.

Whenever i try i get the exeption at 0% of the job:

> INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1510791427999_0007 failed with state
>   FAILED due to: Application application_1510791427999_0007 failed 2
>   times due to Error launching appattempt_1510791427999_0007_000002. Got
>   exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Given
>   NMToken for application : appattempt_1510791427999_0007_000002 is not
>   valid for current node manager.expected : node2.novalocal:45454 found
>   : node3.novalocal:45454

I did some research but i coulnt understand where is the problem or what could be the solution. Can you provide any Help?

Comment: Restart node 3 and 4 nodemanager processes after putting yarn in safe mode. Then try restarting the resource manager

Comment: I followed your suggestion, same happens with the same output

Comment: Sorry, meant node2 and node3. Check the `/etc/hosts` on all the machines... Basically, it looks like `node2` and `node3` are mixed up.